# VB.NET what does comma in parentheses mean?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Say you have:

```
Private _xValues(,) As Double
```

What exactly does that mean VS declaring:

```
Private _xValues(2) As Double
```

or

```
Private _xValues() As Double
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I tried researching and could not find any documentation.

Comment: What ***does it produce***?... 2 dementional array would be my guess...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dk93f6e

Comment: On a side note look into `List(Of)`, we have came a long way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Number of comma's* in an array would tell you the dimension of the array. ie.

```
Private _xValues() As Double 'is 1-D(one dimension) array
Private _xValues(,) As Double 'is 2-D(two dimension) array
Private _xValues(,,) As Double 'is 3-D(three dimension) array
```

So for example

```
Private _xValues(1) As Double 'is 1-D(one dimension) array
Private _xValues(1,2) As Double 'is 2-D(two dimension) array
Private _xValues(1,2,3) As Double 'is 3-D(three dimension) array
```

**EDIT 1:**

As @Codexer pointed it out, writing *numeric* `xValues(1)` inside the parenthesis `()` would define the array size. Thus when you initialize `Dim xValues(5) as Double`, the array `xValues` can carry `MAX 6` elements in it, **not `MAX 5` as said earlier, see Edit 2** . Further, as arrays have *zero* based norm. The *first* element in the array will have the `Index` as `0` and **not 1**. The *last* element's `Index` will be *arraySize - 1*

**EDIT 2:**
Credits to @VisualVincent:

`Dim xValues(5)` is equal to `Dim xValues(0 To 5)` which reserves index `0-5` in *memory* (**this is specific to VB.NET only**).

Comment: You should mention you are setting the max array in your examples since you ***are initializing them***.

Comment: @Codexer would this make my answer complete now?

Comment: It is, but usually people downvote as a deterrent to answering poor questions.

Comment: @VisualVincent _this is specific to VB.NET only_ I'm not sure about it. You might be right. If that is so, you can improve my answer :)

Comment: `the array xValues can carry MAX 5 elements in it` - Not quite, actually it can hold _**6 items**_. `Dim xValues(5)` is equal to `Dim xValues(0 To 5)` which reserves index 0-5 in memory _**(this is specific to VB.NET only)**_. Since as you say the index starts at zero, index 5 is item no. 6. I usually declare my arrays like: `Dim xValues(5 - 1)` to get the size that I want (in this case 5). Try it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CavcEV

Comment: (Had to remove/re-add my previous comment to add the link at the end, didn't see your comment until I'd reposted it, lol) -- `I'm not sure about it` - Well it is specific to VB.NET only. See my fiddle. All you need to do is update your answer to say _"MAX 6 elements"_.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes I checked. Tried with C# but it wasn't the same. Then I shall edit my answer. Thanks for the added info

Comment: @VisualVincent, updated my answer, If there's anything more to add, you can edit it or post your own. Anyways, I didn't knew about this. Thanks for this great insight. Learned something new today!

Comment: Edits are for correcting grammar, readability, etc., _**not**_ for correcting the author. That's why we are commenting instead of editing it ourselves. -- It looks good to me now, though! :)